# Is Google Directions API route recommendation updating according to real-time traffic?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-api, routes, google-directions-api

I'm building a route recommendation app in Android Studio where the user can see the best route between two destinations on the map. I am using Google Maps APIs for that and I know that it's using Dijkstra's algorithm to determine the route. But I wonder if the API can update the route according to real-time traffic, I didn't find any information about that.

Answer (score -2):

Google Maps is updated constantly – literally, every second of every day!

[refer this page](https://geoawesomeness.com/google-maps-update-frequency/#:%7E:text=This%20means%2C%20in%20essence%2C%20Google,million%20places%20around%20the%20world.)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).